# Em R, como transformar tibble em dataframe

Tags: r, data.frame, tibble

Eu tenho uma estrutura tibble resultado do seguinte script, usando o pacote purrr:

```
data %>% group_by(REGIAO , V1023) %>% nest() %>% mutate( teste = map(data, ff))
```

Onde ff é uma funcao particular que eu criei para aplicar em cada grupo REGIAO e V1023. O resultado é basicamente parecido com isto

```
    # A tibble: 18 x 3
         REGIAO V1023                teste
          <chr> <int>               <list>
 1        Norte     1 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
 2        Norte     4 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
 3        Norte     2 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
 4     Nordeste     4 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
 5     Nordeste     1 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
 6     Nordeste     2 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
 7     Nordeste     3 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
 8      Sudeste     4 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
 9      Sudeste     1 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
10      Sudeste     2 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
11      Sudeste     3 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
12          Sul     2 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
13          Sul     4 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
14          Sul     1 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
15 Centro-Oeste     4 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
16 Centro-Oeste     1 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
17 Centro-Oeste     2 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
18 Centro-Oeste     3 <data.frame [3 x 6]>
```

A "coluna" teste é composta por dataframes que tem as mesmas variáveis tanto na suas linhas e nas suas colunas. Ou seja, tem as mesmas dimensões, como podemos ver acima. Eu quero transformar isto em dataframe. Ou seja, quero empilhar cada dataframe da variavel teste, mas sem perder sua REGIAO e nem a variavel V1023. 
Alguma solução?

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta com o resultado de `dput(head(data2))` onde `data2` é esse `tibble`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a função [`unnest`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unnest.html) do [`tidyr`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org):

#### Exemplo:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(purrr)
> library(tidyr)
> 
> df <- tibble(x = 1:10, y = 1:10) %>%
+   mutate(z = map2(x, y, ~data.frame(a = .x + 1:5, b = .y + 1:5)))
> 
> print(df)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
       x     y                    z
   <int> <int>               <list>
 1     1     1 <data.frame [5 x 2]>
 2     2     2 <data.frame [5 x 2]>
 3     3     3 <data.frame [5 x 2]>
 4     4     4 <data.frame [5 x 2]>
 5     5     5 <data.frame [5 x 2]>
 6     6     6 <data.frame [5 x 2]>
 7     7     7 <data.frame [5 x 2]>
 8     8     8 <data.frame [5 x 2]>
 9     9     9 <data.frame [5 x 2]>
10    10    10 <data.frame [5 x 2]>
> 
> df %>% unnest(z)
# A tibble: 50 x 4
       x     y     a     b
   <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     1     2     2
 2     1     1     3     3
 3     1     1     4     4
 4     1     1     5     5
 5     1     1     6     6
 6     2     2     3     3
 7     2     2     4     4
 8     2     2     5     5
 9     2     2     6     6
10     2     2     7     7
# ... with 40 more rows
```